# Why would you use 好き to describe a favorite object?

Tags: word-choice, usage

After taking some notes from various classes, I have come across some of the same translations:

好{す}きな音楽{おんがく}：Favorite Music

好{す}きな人{ひと}：Favorite person

etc.

Why would one use 好{す}き instead of 大好{だいす}き　or 大事{だいじ}? Are all correct, and its just a personal choice? (with the occasional exception of 大事{だいじ})
Thanks!

Comment: @Chcr Would you mind making that an answer and possibly expanding on why an individual would choose 大好き as opposed to 好き and vice-versa?

Comment: すき simply refers to whether you like something or not. It does not mean "favorite". As such, these questions can have more than one answer. If you wanted to ask for a single most favorite, I would suggest wording such as "一番好きな".

Comment: @Chcr Please don't write answers as comments.  Answers in the comment section may be removed without notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to say favorite, e.g. 好き、大好き、お気{き}に入{い}り、大{だい}のお気{き}に入{い}り, etc. Use of either of these is a personal choice, but of course using a 大 would indicate a higher degree so 大好き＞好き and 大のお気に入り＞お気に入り as in the following examples:

> 好きな教科{きょうか}は理科{りか}と音楽{おんがく}です。
>
> My favorite subjects are science and music.
>
> 算数{さんすう}も好きだが、社会{しゃかい}が大好きです。
>
> I like arithmetic too, but social studies is my favorite.
>
> 高校時代{こうこうじだい}からロックが好きでした。特にGuns N' Rosesはその時の大のお気に入りのバンドでした。
>
> I liked rock music since high school. In particular, Guns N' Roses was my most favorite band at the time.